# How to send email from google sheet with the sheet as a PDF attachment

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets, spreadsheet, email-attachments

I have a google sheet that has two sheets, **Form Responses** and **report**:
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yTz3.jpg)

when a form submits report sheet change with the last form or last row of the responses sheet.
I want to send an email to the person who submits the form and attach the report sheet as PDF
after sending email write *sent email* in column e:
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er6c8.jpg)

email to: Form Responses column b
subject: *some text* and Form Responses column a
cc: ABC@yahoo.com
body: *some text* and Form Responses column f
attach: report sheet as PDF

i used this code but it doesn't work

```
 function onSubmit(e){
  Logger.log('submit ran');

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var sa = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
  var sB = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
var sf = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue();


  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sheetgId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  var email =  Session.getUser().getEmail();
  var subject = SB;
  var body = Sf;


  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/..............................................................=0&single=true&output=pdf";


  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)

  var contents = result.getContent();

 if (emailSent !== "EMAIL_SENT") { 

      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:SB+".pdf", content:contents, mimeType:"application//pdf"}]});
       sheet.getRange().setValue("EMAIL_SENT");

          SpreadsheetApp.flush();

        }
  }
```

I get the url from spreadsheet>file>publish to web>publish report tab as pdf

---

i rewrite the code but get error "**TypeError: report.getAs is not a function (line 36, file "Code")**"

```
   function onSubmit(e){


 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getAet();
 
  var calculate = ss.getSheets()[2];
 var Responses = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
var report = ss.getSheets()[1];


  


 var sh = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 8).getValue();
 


   var cell = calculate.getRange("b2");
  cell.setFormula(sh); 
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 

  var email = sB;
  var subject = 
  var body = se;
  
  var calculate = ss.getSheets()[2];
 vafunction onSubmit(e){
  Logger.log('submit ran');


  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 
  var calculate = ss.getSheets()[2];
 var Responses = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
var report = ss.getSheets()[1];


  


  var lastRow = Responses.getLastRow();
  var sa = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
var se = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5).getValue();
v
  cell.setFormula(sh); 
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 

  var email = sB;

  var body = se;
  
  var calculate = ss.getSheets()[2];
 var Responses = ss.getSheets()[0]; 

var pdf = report.getAs('application/pdf');

 
     
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body,  {attachments:[pdf]});
     sf.setvalue("EMAIL_SENT");
      
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  }
r Responses = ss.getSheets()[0]; 

var pdf = report.getAs('application/pdf');

 
     
      MailApp.sendEmail(t ,body,  {attachments:[pdf]});
     sf.setvalue("EMAIL_SENT");
      
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to send the users the whole response sheet as PDF, or just the responses that where saved until the moment when the user filled the form? If other users fill the form afterward, will every user get a second email?. And please post any code you have tried so far.

Comment: each user should enter Code(user name) and password and receive email about his or her specific data and for next user data will change and email sent just to that user( not all of them)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Apps Script for this.

You as the owner of the form and response sheet, can create a bound script and use the Gmail and Forms services to create your desired pdf, and sent it to your users.

You can also create triggers to check when a new response is submitted.

---

**References:**

- [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms)
- [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail)
- [Apps Script + Forms quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms)
- [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: I see the code you added. It appears you have typos on the `MailApp.sendEmail()` line. Can you share which error you are having? and ideally which line of code is throwing it?

Answer (score 0):

I dug out an old example and was using getAs() to send a document so if you only want one sheet you would just create a new spreadsheet with the info you do want to send.

```
var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(Title,y,x);
```

Set whatever values you want in it and then

```
var pdf = newSheet.getAs('application/pdf');
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments:[pdf]} );
```

I suggest creating a new spreadsheet because you cannot convert just one tab to PDF.

Comment: TypeError: report.getAs is not a function (line 36, file "Code")